# How to Unit Test a method with a JavaFX Filechooser

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, javafx

How do i write a JUNIT test for a method that brings up a JavaFX Filechooser?
the unit test gets stuck awaiting for user input from that Filechooser

```
@Test
public void testGetPath() {
  try {
        myController mc= new myController();
        String s = uiController.getPath();
        assertNotNull(s);
  }



public String getPath() {
String s = "";
Task<Void> t = new Task<Void>() {

  @Override
  protected Void call() throws Exception {
      FileChooser myFileChooser = new FileChooser ("/home/default");

      File file =  myFileChooser.showSaveDialog(appStage);

      if (file != null) {
        s = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
      }
  }

};

Platform.runLater(t);

while (!t.isDone())
  ;

return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a mock for myController which would implement the same interface but the mock would just return a file path without any user intervention.